# くらい and ほど -- Where do they come from?

Tags: etymology, history

I've searched for a while now but haven't really found anything that answers my question.

I would like to know where ほど and くらい come from and how they got to mean such different things.

I know that ほど is 程, which means "extent", and recently I found out that くらい is 位 so it means "rank". But I can't find a book or a site or anything that talks about them.

Does anyone have any information?

Comment: I'd say ほど is "degree" because "extent" means "stretch" by etymology. By the way, what do you mean by "such different things"?

Comment: Thanks, and I mean that both can mean "about, approximately", one can mean "at least" etc.
I believe the meaning of these words by itself can explain all the different meanings, but that's what I would like to find, some actual files or something

Comment: If you don't care about etymology, you can have: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2392/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/408/7810

Comment: ほど often means highest level, but くらい can express any level.

Comment: Thanks broccoli forest but I had already read those :(
Takahiro Waki yes that's what I feel too ^^
If someone has a good book about history of japanese grammar or something that could help me understand mroe about things like that, please 教えて btw :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Derivation of 程【ほど】

The modern reading *hodo* is a shift from older *hoto*.

**Speculation:** This element might be the same *hoto* that appears as a compounding element in various verbs, apparently related to the adverb *potopoto* "drippingly", in reference to liquids.  These verbs include:

- 迸る【ほとばしる】: "to gush, to surge".  Compound of *hoto* + *hashiru*, where *hoto* seems to mean "lots of water"
- 潤びる【ほとびる】: "to swell or soften with water".  from older ほとぶ.  Compound of *hoto* + suffix *-bu*, which appears to be an instance of `/b/` ↔ `/m/` alternation with suffix *-mu*, "to become like, to appear like".  The *hoto* element could again be interpreted as "lots of water", in the context of "having" or "full of".

If 程【ほど】 derives from the same *hoto*, it might be a reference to "an amount (of something)".

#### Derivation of 位【くらい】

Originally a compound of 座【くら】 ("seat") + 居【ゐ】 ("being, sitting", the 連用形【れんようけい】 or continuative form of verb 居る【ゐる】 "to be or sit in a place").

The initial sense was "where one sits", used then as a euphemism for one's social standing.  (For that matter, the English term "standing" is a similar kind of usage.)  Over time, this sense of "rank" was extended to refer to various other things.

#### Usage

My personal sense for the subtleties of word usage is limited as a non-native speaker.  My gut feeling is that 程【ほど】 is used in places where English would have "as much (or some other adjective) as" or "so much (or some other adjective) that", as in:

- 「ＡさんはＢさん[ほ]{●}[ど]{●}淋【さみ】しい」, "A is **as lonely as** B".
- 「Ａが高ければ高い[ほ]{●}[ど]{●}、Ｂが大きい」, literally "if A is high, then **as high as** it is, B is that big" → "the higher the A, the bigger the B".
- 「どれ[ほ]{●}[ど]{●}食べたのですか？」, literally "You ate **as much as** which?" → "**How much** did you eat?"

That said, 位【くらい】 is also used the same way as the last pattern: 「どれ[く]{●}[ら]{●}[い]{●}食べた？」.  In fact, 位【くらい】 seems to be more common than 程【ほど】 in this usage.  However, 位【くらい】 is never used for the `[ADJ]`ければ`[ADJ]`ほど construction, and for the first pattern, it requires a の where 程【ほど】 just comes right after the noun.

I'll leave a qualitative analysis of the different uses to other posters.

Answer (score 0):

I think they come from the noun form of the words.

People have needs to modify their saying, for example:

She was so happy that she felt like crying.

Weren't there the usage "so...that", this sentence would be lacking a little expressiveness.

Accordingly, 彼女は泣きたいくらい嬉しい。/ 彼女は嬉しくて泣きたいくらいだ。

By the way, I think くらい means position as well.