# What is the difference between くらい～はない & ほど～はない?

Tags: grammar, jlpt

- リーさん**ぐらい**動物好きな人はいない。
- リーさん**ほど**動物好きな人はいない。

What is the difference between these two sentences.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, the two sentences are interchangeable and there is almost no difference in meaning.

But that does not mean くらい/ぐらい/ほど are always interchangeable. For more generic discussion, see the following questions:

- [The difference between くらい and ほど in hyperbole](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2392/5010)
- [What is the difference between 「ほど」 (hodo) and 「ぐらい」 (gurai)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/408/5010)